# Get all database names with mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

How can I get the name of all databases with Mongoid?

I found this:

```
connection = Mongoid.master.connection 
connection.database_names
```

but it is not working. It turns out this error: `undefined method master 'for Mongoid: Module (NoMethodError)`

Any help?

Comment: So database names or collection names?

Comment: Sorry, i saw error on my question and fix. I need a list of all databases names.

Answer (score 1):

I got with moped. Maybe it is not the best way, but it is working for me.

```
session = Moped::Session.new(["127.0.0.1:27017"])
databases = session.databases.first[1]
```